# Cannot Terminate my Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, terminate

I have created a loop but cannot figure out how to stop it. I want the loop to stop when the active cell is empty although even when the cell is empty it continues looping.

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Sheets("UNIT BUYSHEET").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("PAYOFF INFO & LIEN RELEASE").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("AUTHORIZATION FOR PAYOFF").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("GUARANTEE OF TITLE").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Sheets("FLEET LIST & QUOTE").Select
    Rows("9:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Loop
```

This is what I have created so far, it prints forms for the selected "unit" and once all the forms are printed it removes the unit and prints the next units forms. I have added multiple units and the loop works great but it wont stop when there are no more units. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`IsEmpty` checks is a value is empty (null). The cell itself never is, but it's value can be. Change the check a little bit:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm having the same problem. The only way I can stop it is if I force close excel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ruled out the impact of the other sheets on your code?

I have just tested this block of code on my own spreadsheet, and it stops exactly when there is no more data:

```
Sub thisWorks()
    Rows("9:9").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Rows("9:9").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

3 original suggestions:

1)
Firstly, try explicitly selecting a cell at the end of the process with (some versions of Excel have strange bugs in them):

```
Rows("9:9").EntireRow.Range("A1").Select
```

This is based on the code you provided which already says `Rows("9:9").Select`.

2) Secondly, try using `ActiveCell.Value = ""` instead of `IsEmpty()`. Perhaps there is data in the cell you don't know about.

3) Finally, try trimming the cell value inside the blank check:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Trim(ActiveCell))
```

---

It is difficult to say much more without knowing more about your data.

Comment: The problem with defining the end cell is that cell varies by user so sometimes it will run through 50 cells and sometimes it will only run through 5, that's why I wanted it to stop when the cell was empty. 

When I put in IsBlank() it says that the Sub or Function is not defined. Unfortunately, I don't really know what that means.

I added the trim and it still looped past the desired end point...

Thank you for the suggestions though, I'm really looking for anything at this point. ha...

Comment: @vfank You are implicitly selecting the first cell in row 9 already (based on the code provided). I'm just suggesting you explicitly select it to remove any doubt as to which cell is active. (unless your provided code is not really true?)

Answer (score 0):

`IsEmpty` operates on a `Variant`. `ActiveCell` is a `Range` object which gets converted to a `Variant` so `IsEmpty` can operate on it. *That* variant is therefore not empty. So `IsEmpty` will return `False` in your case.

The fix is simple: use `IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)`.

Comment: That's what GolezTrol suggested but it acts as though nothing has changed, it still loops past the desired stopping point. Would seeing the actual spreadsheet help at all?